# Get body to flux if I have list of strings in server request body and iterate over them

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

In my route I have one Post endpoint for which I expecting to accept the list of strings which I will then proccessing in handler.

My question is, how can I get these list of strings from ServerRequest body and iterate over them using Flux?

**My Router**

```
@Configuration
public class TestUrlRouter {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routes(TestUrlHandler handler) {
        return RouterFunctions.route(
                RequestPredicates.POST("/urls").and(RequestPredicates.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)),
                handler::testUrls
        );
    }
}
```

**My handler**

```
@Component
public class TestUrlHandler {

    @Autowired
    private TestUrlService testUrlService;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> testUrls(ServerRequest request) {

        request.bodyToFlux(List.class) // how to iterate over strings?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved it by this code:

```
@Component
public class TestUrlHandler {

    @Autowired
    private TestUrlService testUrlService;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> testUrls(ServerRequest request) {

        ParallelFlux<TestUrlResult> results = request.bodyToMono(String[].class)
                .flatMapMany(Flux::fromArray)
                .flatMap(url -> testUrlService.testUrls(url))
                .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("Testing of URLS is done."));

        return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(results, TestUrlResult.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a POST request with a json payload that looks like this
["uuid-1","uuid-2"]
What would the above code look like in that case?

Comment: I think that comment from @Barath it solving your case.

Comment: Its not, as I have to process a json array as post body thus cannot use wrapper

Comment: So then `request.bodyToMono(String.class).map(json -> new ObjectMapper().readTree(json))` something like that... Check how to work with Jackson library.

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of ways of achieving it.

Keeping it simple(modify as per your need).

```java
protected static class WrapperList{

        private List<String> urls;

// getter & setter
}
```

```java
public Mono<ServerResponse> testUrls(ServerRequest request) {       

        return request.bodyToFlux(WrapperList.class).flatMap(wrapperList -> {
            wrapperList.getUrls().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
            return ServerResponse.ok().build();
        }).take(1).next();

    }
```

request payload:

```
{
  "urls": ["url1","url2"]
}
```

Comment: I cannot use wrapper :/ I will always receive List of urls  `["http://imgur.com/", "http://www.cumhuriyyet.net/", "https://d2zfqthxsdq309.cloudfront.net/"]`